# adding xml content to sphinx generated doc

Tags: python, include, python-sphinx, substitution

So here is my problem. I'm trying to generate documentation for my project using sphinx and managed to get the basic working, like adding modules and images. So a basic index.rst would look like:

```
.. |tvb| replace:: `The Project`
.. _tvb: http://www.myproject.org

.. |logo| image:: img/evil_tvb_logo_transparent.svg
    :alt: The Project
    :align: top 
    :height: 148
    :target: tvb_


|logo|
*******
My Modules
=========================

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 6

   tvb
```

'tvb' here contains top level modules and links to sub-packages and so on. This seems to work fine and the html documentation is generated accordingly.

However I have a couple of xml-defined methods that are used in part of the project to call some matlab functions, and I would like to make that content also available for sphinx, even if just as pure text or the actual xml. I can't seem to find a way to do this. So basically I would need to be able to for example in package: pck1.pck2 if i have functions.xml, to add in the toc at that level a link to a html that will display the content from that xml.

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards,
Bogdan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the documentation, it seems that [literalinclude](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#directive-literalinclude) might be what you're looking for:

```
.. literalinclude:: functions.xml
```