# Documenting XML with sphinx

Tags: python, xml, python-sphinx

I have a python project that i am documenting with sphinx. The project reads in an xml configuration file. What is the best way to document this configuration file? Can i include an xml schema somehow? Or have a nice cascaded example? I know i can just type it out, but is there a better way to make it look pretty and easy to write/maintain?

All i have found is ways to include xml in the sphinx to change the structure etc.

I am looking for a way which is highly integrated and easy to use.

Thanks :D

Comment: question reworded here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49538195/sphinx-how-to-automatically-generate-documentation-from-xml-schema-xsd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8913336/adding-xml-content-to-sphinx-generated-doc) recommends using Sphinx's [literalinclude](http://sphinx-doc.org/markup/code.html?highlight=include#directive-literalinclude) directive.

This will allow you to include the literal content of the XML file which you could document with standard XML comment strings `<!-- -->`.  The directive allows you to specify the language of the content which presumably affects final rendering.

Comment: yeah i saw that. That is just the text method though. Im kind of envisioning a nice expandable xml tags ... but i have been looking and i can't find anything else :/ but thanks :D

Comment: I think the alternative would be to write a new domain for Sphinx (http://sphinx-doc.org/domains.html) which allows it to parse the XML in a more native manner.

Comment: Or rather, a domain for the DTD that defines the schema.

Comment: Thats actually a great idea, but i only have two configuration files in this project so probably not worth it :/ but next time :D