# Sphinx: How to automatically generate documentation from XML Schema (XSD)

Tags: xml, xsd, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

We want to document an XML file structure using the self-documented XSD schema file.

As Sphinx provides some autodoc support for some languages, is there an equivalent way to generate some kind of good looking documentation directly from XSD ?

NB: we use Sphinx / ReStructuredText for project documentation.

Comment: Sphinx has no built-in functionality for generating reST-based documentation from XSD, and I don't know any other tool that can do it. Perhaps you can build something yourself based on this project: https://github.com/averagehuman/python-html2rest. Or use some other tool that does not involve reST/Sphinx at all: https://stackoverflow.com/a/533257/407651.

Answer (score 0):

A great XSD documentation generator you can find here: http://www.flexdoc.xyz/flexdoc-xml/xsddoc/

It generates highly detailed XML schema documentation with diagrams:

[image]

Comment: that's interesting but unfortunately there is no simple integration capabilities with Sphinx-Doc, which is what we want to do. maybe we could investigate later.