# Embed xml file in rst

Tags: xml, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I'm generating a documentation with sphinx and i would like to include some `xml` examples that are stored in separate files. Is it possible to include an external `xml` file in such a way that the output doc uses the proper highlighting?

I tried `.. include:: file.xml` inside my `rst`. but the highlighting was broken and I could not fix it.

Comment: I think you want `literalinclude`: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8913336/407651, https://stackoverflow.com/q/18801693/407651

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`literalinclude` directive](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#directive-literalinclude).

```
.. literalinclude:: file.xml
    :language: xml
```